# Why is the icon and list content not displaying in a horizontal line?

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I am trying to create 3 icons with lists under them to be displayed at the bottom of the screen and when I use a float: left css on the it. they display how I want them to, but the background will not encompass them becuase they are no longer housed within the background content div. I am also trying to center the div that all 3 lists ( and icons) are within to be displayed in the center of the screen, but when I use a margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; to center them the div will still not float to the center of the screen.

HTML

```
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/KendraTemplate.dwt"     codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>kendraRossUtahState</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<link href="../CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.MenuDisplay {
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
background-color:#DDD;
}
 .ListItemDisplay {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:2%;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }

</style>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>
<body background="../Images/UtahMoutains-copy7.png" style=" background-  repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-attachment:fixed;   background-size:cover; margin:0px;">
<header>

<div style=" float:left; width:100%; background-color:#DDD;    position:relative; margin:0px;">

        <a href="../index.html"><img src="../Images/utahGovLogo.png" style="  float:left; padding:20px;"></a>

        <img src="../Images/Search Button.png" style="float:right; padding:20px;">

</div>
    <nav style="z-index:9; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <ul style="list-style:none; text-align:center; background- color:#DDD; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, Neue,sans-serif; font-size:120%;  color:#666; margin:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">Government
              <ul class="MenuDisplay">
                    <li><a href="executive.html" class="linkstyle">Executive  Branch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="legislative.html"    class="linkstyle">Legislative Branch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="judicial.html" class="linkstyle">Judicial Branch</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of  Government  drop down menu-->
            </li><!-- end of Government Button-->

            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">About Utah
              <ul class="MenuDisplay">
                    <li><a href="executive.html" class="linkstyle">Recreational</a></li>
                    <li><a href="legislative.html" class="linkstyle">Geographical</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end of  About Utah  drop down menu-->
            </li><!-- end of About Utah Button-->

            <li class="ListItemDisplay" style="cursor:default;">
                <a href="about.html" class="linkstyle">
                    Fun Facts
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</header>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
<div class="outerwrapperrec">
<div class="contentrec">
    <div id="graphrec">
        <h2>Utah Recreational Information</h2>
        <div id="innergraphrec">
            <img src="../Images/UtahrecFacts.png" width="470" height="479" alt=""/> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="innerwrapperrec">
        <div class="listItemcontent">
            <p style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF;">
                Boaters have the responsibility to practice and advocate safe and ethical use of our waterways. This responsibility includes properly registering boats, learning and obeying boating safety laws and rules, and sharing waterways with other boaters, swimmers, and anglers.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="listItemrec">
        <div id="listicon">
            <div id="iconimage">
                <img src="../Images/ohvIcon.png" width="103" height="103" alt="OHV symbol Icon"/>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>OHV Trails</li>
                <li>Licensing Information</li>
                <li>Public Safety Info</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>

        <div id="listicon">
            <div id="iconimage">
                <img src="../Images/sailboatIcon.png" width="103" height="103" alt="Boat Symbol Icon"/>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>Utah's Lakes</li>
                <li>Boat Licensing Info</li>
                <li>Boating Safty Info</li>
                <li>Water Conservation Info</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>

        <div id="listicon">
            <div id="iconimage">
                <img src="../Images/hikerIcon.png" width="103" height="103" alt="Hiker Symbol Icon"/>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>Trails</li>
                <li>Scenic Overlooks</li>
                <li>State Parks</li>
                <li>Hike Safty Info</li>
                <li>Camping & Swimming Info</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        </div><!-- End ListItemrec div-->
    </div><!-- End Innerwrapperrec div-->
</div><!-- End Contentrec div-->
</div><!-- End outerwrapperrec div-->

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->


</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

CSS

```
html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-width:800px;

}

body{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-width:100px;
}

.header1{
width:100%; 
}

nav ul li ul {
display: none;
width:auto;
clear:both;
position:relative;
text-align:left; 
padding:10px;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}

.MenuDisplay{
z-index:9;  
}

.ListItemDisplay{
z-index:9;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top: 100%;
left:0;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}

nav ul li {
position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul li {
width:180px;
text-align:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

#aboutimages {
height:auto;
}

 #innerwrapperabout {
 height:100%;

 }

 #mainwrapper{
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 padding:25px;
 min-width:350px;
 position:relative;
 background-color:#00717B;
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 }

 #mainwrapperabout{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 }

 #contentwrapperabout{
 height:100%;
 width:800px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 }

 #aboutimagepng{
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 min-width:50px;
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 }

 .a-btn{
 background: #f0ad4e;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position:absolute;
 padding:10px;
 display:block;

 }

 .linkstyle{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:inherit
 }

 .a-btn span{
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: block;
 color:#FFF;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
 padding:3px;
 width:auto;
 line-height:normal;
 position:relative;
 }
 .a-btn span:nth-child(1), 
 .a-btn span:nth-child(3),
 .a-btn span:nth-child(4),
 .a-btn span:nth-child(5){
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0;
 }
 .a-btn span:nth-child(1){
 opacity: 0.2;
 position:relative;
 }
 #bubble1:hover{
 background-image:url(../Images/saltlakecityskyline2.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: -40px -50px;

 }

 #bubble2:hover{
 background-image:url(../Images/Dinosour2.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: -250px -0px;
 }

 #bubble3:hover{
 background-image:url(../Images/California-Seagull_DARKER.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: -50px 0px;
 }

 #bubble4:hover{
 background-image:url(../Images/Honey-Bee_DARKER.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: -108px -2px;
 }

 #bubble5:hover{
 background-image:url(../Images/Rocky%20Mountain%20Elk_DARKER.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position: -50px 0px;

 }

 .a-btn:hover span:nth-child(3){
 opacity: 1;
 position:relative;
 }
 .a-btn:hover span:nth-child(4){
 opacity: 1;
 position:relative;
 }

 .a-btn:hover span:nth-child(5){
 opacity: 1;
 position:relative;
}
.a-btn:hover span:nth-child(2){
opacity: 0;
position:relative;

}

#aboutimagemain {
display:block;
float:left;
padding:30px;
width:300px;
height:auto;
background-color:#5B9CB0;
margin:10px;

}

#aboutimage1 {
clear:both;
width:auto;


}

#mainwrapperlegislative {
height:100%;
width:760px;
min-width:350px;
position:relative;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#00717B;

}

#legislativeislands{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:780px;
position:relative;
height:100%;

}

.outerwrapperrec{
width:100%;
}

.contentrec{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.innerwrapperrec{
background-color:#00717B;
padding:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:800px;
}

#listicon{
color:#FFF;
display:block;
width:200px;
position:relative;
}

#iconimage{
}

#graphrec{
text-align:center;
}

#innergraphrec{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.listItemrec{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: If you make a JSFiddle (or similar) it is much easier to visualise the problem and therefore help you :)

Comment: the images' links could be wrong. Mind the folder hierarchy and folder name in css, as they case-sensitive.